# Visual Studio Code: "'tslib' cannot be found" error in Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, single-page-application

Basically, all I'm doing is starting a new Angular project and loading it into a workspace. It doesn't look as if VS Code can do any linting or code sense because of this error. It's spitting up this error data:

```
{
    "resource": "/Users/<snip!>/angular-project/src/app/app.module.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2354",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 13,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 26,
    "endColumn": 3
}
```

I found an old bug somewhere that said `moduleResolution` of `tsconfig.json` had to be set to `node`, but Angular CLI has already done that for me...

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit: Steps I took to get here (using version 8 as of this writing):

1. Install Angular CLI: `$ npm install -g @angular/cli`
2. Create the project: `$ ng new angular-project`
3. Serve the project: `$ ng serve`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What is the angular version ? Also could you upload the code that show the error or take a screen shot of it

Comment: I could... but I've tried manipulating code to try to get rid of it and any code in the project that gets evaluated gives the same error.

Comment: FWIW I'm using the latest angular stuffs and CLI. Version 8.0.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is my package.json file using angular 8. Check to see if you have tslib install or not.

Also delete package-lock.json and delete node_modules folder then run `npm i` again

```
{
  "name": "ngrx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```